# Inadmissible construct in symbolic method

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, analytic-combinatorics

I am studying the symbolic method and a question arose.

A construction is admissible if by associating a new class $\mathcal{C}=\Phi(\mathcal{A}_1,...,\mathcal{A}_j)$ , this implies that there is an operator Psi on generating functions, such that $C(x)=\Psi(A_1(x),.. .,A_j(x))$

For example, in the unlabeled world we have $\mathcal{C}=\text{Seq}(\mathcal{A})\to C(x)= \frac{1}{1-A(x)}$

My doubt is there are inadmissible constructions?  Could someone give me an example of an inadmissible construction?

Comment: How do you define a construction?

Answer (score 1):

Section I.2 of Flajolet/Sedgewick's text gives an example:

Let $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ be combinatorial classes. Let $\mathcal{B}_n$ and $\mathcal{C}_n$ denote the set of elements of size $n$ from $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ respectively.

The usual set-theoretic union is not admissible, because
$$\text{card}(\mathcal{B}_n \cup \mathcal{C}_n)
= \text{card}(\mathcal{B}_n) + \text{card}(\mathcal{C}_n) - \text{card}(\mathcal{B}_n \cap \mathcal{C}_n).$$
Specifically, the cardinality of $\mathcal{B}_n \cup \mathcal{C}_n$ is not a function of $\text{card}(\mathcal{B}_0),\text{card}(\mathcal{B}_1),\ldots$ and $\text{card}(\mathcal{C}_0),\text{card}(\mathcal{C}_1),\ldots$.

If $\mathcal{B}_n$ and $\mathcal{C}_n$ are disjoint however, we recover the admissible sum construction $A(z) = B(z) + C(z)$.